# Pointers to other structures within a structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

My lecturer has presented the following piece of code, with an insufficient explanation of what it represents.

```
typedef struct _s {
    int         value;
    struct _s   *next;
}  STACKITEM;

STACKITEM    *stack = NULL;
```

1. I understand what pointers and structures are. However, I do not know what it means to have a pointer to a structure, within a structure. Please clarify and elaborate on this concept.
2. I do not understand why the structure is declared typedef. This seems redundant for the following reasons:

A typical structure states as follows.

```
struct struct_format_name { 
members;
} individual_struct_object_name;
```

Therefore, we have declared an object to be a structure, and given this format of a structure the name _s. So what was the point of using typedef? Except for the typedef keyword, it is the same format that you would use to declare any structure.

3. I would like clarification on the difference between a pointer to a structure pointing to a structured format, as done above, and a pointer to a structure pointing to a particular structure.

I suspect that a pointer to a structure pointing to a structured format, as done above, can point to ANY structure of that format? However, a pointer to a structure pointing to a concrete structure can only point to that particular structure, rather than other structures of the same format?

Comment: One question to a question, please.

Comment: Yes, the typedef is useless (in most cases) and confusing (as in your case) My advice: if you don't need it: don't use it.

Comment: @wildplasser The answer by xaxxon says the opposite?

Comment: The first struct is a linked list: a chain of objects, where each object points to the next in line. The typedef could be a convenience, or more likely: to hide the implementation. Much like `FILE` is a typedef of the underlying file struct.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks. So does that mean that Xaxxon's answer is incorrect?

Comment: Xaxxion's answer does not conflict with my opinion. In fact, he states that *in the end* the two forms are equivalent (the result is the same), and my opinion is that you only need one form (and that introducing another name for something that already has a name is not needed. and possibly confusing)

Comment: @ThePointer: No, arguably, it doesn't cover all of your questions, but there's nothing in there that strikes me as incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand what pointers and structures are. However, I do not understand what it means to have a pointer to a structure, within a structure. Please clarify and elaborate on this concept.

This is a common C implementation of a data structure known as a *[singly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)*, where each element in the list explicitly points to the following element.  In this case, each instance of a `struct _s` points to another instance of a `struct _s`, like so:

```
+---+---+         +---+---+        +---+---+
|   |   | ----->  |   |   | -----> |   |   |
+---+---+         +---+---+        +---+---+
                                     ^   ^
                                     |   |
                                     |   +---- next
                                     +-------- value
```

You can implement a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) using a linked list structure, which is what your instructor is doing.  A "push" operation would dynamically create a new `STACKITEM`, save the integer value to it, and make that new `STACKITEM` the head of the list (a.k.a. the top of the stack).  The `stack` pointer always points to the first element in the list (`NULL` if the list is empty).

```
stack: |||

push( &stack, 1 );

       +---+---+
stack: | 1 |   |---|||
       +---+---+
```

Repeated calls to `push` will add a new element at the head of the list:

```
push( &stack, 2 );

       +---+---+    +---+---+
stack: | 2 |   |--->| 1 |   |---|||
       +---+---+    +---+---+

push( &stack, 3 );

       +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
stack: | 3 |   |--->| 2 |   |--->| 1 |   |---|||
       +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
```

The code would look something like

```
void push( STACKITEM **stack, int value )
{
  STACKITEM *newItem = malloc( sizeof *newItem );
  if ( newItem )
  {
    newItem->value = value;
    newItem->next  = *stack;    // newItem now points to former top of stack
    *stack         = newItem;   // newItem is now the top of the stack
  }
}
```

A "pop" operation just works in reverse - it removes the first element of the list by setting the `stack` pointer to point to the next element and frees that element's memory:

```
void pop( STACKITEM **stack )
{
  STACKITEM *top = *stack;
  if ( top )
  {
    *stack = top->next;
    free( top );
  }
}

pop( &stack );

       +---+---+    +---+---+
stack: | 2 |   |--->| 1 |   |---|||
       +---+---+    +---+---+

pop( &stack );

       +---+---+
stack: | 1 |   |---|||
       +---+---+

pop( &stack );

stack: |||
```

> I do not understand why the structure is declared typedef. This seems redundant for the following reasons:

`typedef` serves two basic purposes:

1. Simplify complex type names
2. Abstract away implementation details

In this case, your instructor is aiming for 2 - abstracting away the `struct`-ness of the stack item type.  Unfortunately, if you as the *user* of the type have to be aware of implementation details, then this doesn't serve much of a purpose.

NOTE: Your instructor should not be using a leading underscore in the tag name; identifiers with leading underscores are reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This is called a linked list. The pointer `next` is what allows you to browse the list by having each element point to the next one, and having the last one have `next` point to `NULL`, so you know you're at the end. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list You're not actually storing a structure, you're storing a pointer to the next element, think of it as an array, but where instead of the elements being aligned, each of them points to the next element using its address instead.

As for the `next` pointer the reason it is declared with the struct keyword is that the `STACKITEM` type does not exist yet (it's defined after the structure's definition).

Answer (score 2):

> A typical structure is declared as follows.

Only if you never want to create one ever again in the future.  The syntax you are questioning is by far the typical way to declare a struct.

The typedef allows you to refer to it by the shorter name of `struct_format_name` instead of `struct struct_format_name`.

Comment: Upon further research, I do not think your answer is correct. I can create another structure of the same format by referring to it by its tag. In this case, that would be struct_format_name. Feel free to correct me.

Comment: Oh, sorry.   I misread what you said.  Anyhow, the common practice is to declare the struct in a header file and then create instances of it later - you normally only create one at the same time as you define its structure when you're only going to make one ever.   The typedef bit just saves you from having type type "struct struct_type" every time -- you save a "struct"

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Thank you. I will use your comments for future reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer within a structure is no different from a pointer outside of a structure, and a pointer to a structure type can point to any object of that type.

There is no way to define a type that can only point to a specific object.

Your code and your lecturer's code don't accomplish the same thing, so there's no redundancy.
You're defining both a type and an object; they're defining a type and a different name for that type.
(It sounds a little bit like you're confusing types with objects.)

Their `typedef` isn't strictly necessary but is a very common way to avoid having to type `struct` whenever you use a structure type.

And your variant is very *a*typical.
Types are most often defined globally while variables are declared as locally as possible.